# Create a measure of racial diverstiy based on percent of population

Tags: standard-deviation

Prelude, I'm moving my family to California and am looking at locations and school districts.  One of the measures my wife and I are interested in is a diverse student body.

I have a spreadsheet of all the schools I'm interested in with columns indicating percent of a race.  So 30% white, 10% back, 10% Asian, etc.  What I'd like is a fairly simple formula that can give me a indication of the spread of ranges.  Maybe just a standard deviation would work?  Thanks for the assistance.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps entropy might be what you are looking for? See this Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)). If the proportion in each ethnic group is $p_i$ then you form

$$
- \sum p_i \log p_i
$$

This is maximised when the ethnic groups are all equally represented which is one definition of diversity.

Comment: I read through the entropy article and I definitely think that is the way to go, but my math skills stopped a long time ago.  Would you be able to turn that formula into an example equation for me?  Thanks

Comment: Convert your percentages to proportions 0 to 1). Take the log of each and multiply it by the proportion. Add them all up. Reverse its sign. Does that help?

Comment: That was PERFECT!  It works like a charm.  Expected values line up just like they should

Answer (score 1):

The standard deviation is a bad estimator of diversity, i think we can agree that the most diverse school would be one that the race distribution is closest to that of the population. (Suppose the school is 99.9% white and 0.01% Asian, it would have a higher sd than that of 50% white , 50% Asian)

So if you can get the race distribution in the state and run a goodness of fit test against each school distribution, the one with the highest statistic would be i guess the most diverse.